# Single Page application with react and node

Tags: single-page-application

Please show me how to make SPA with minimal code with react or any reference to simple projects. I want to know how routing render only some part of the loaded html.

Comment: with all due respect - though a good question for newbies, you should rather google about it & not to post it here. People on stack want to see and help with code.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: thanks and sorry at once :) . I will try it and if anything go wrong then i will post it here.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-on-the-server-for-beginners-build-a-universal-react-and-node-app  michael corleone sir can you help me "set NODE_ENV=production | node_modules/.bin/webpack -p" is not creating bundle file . I am on doing it on windows.